# In Java linux platform how can i connect to ttyS0 or ttyUSB0 for sending and receiving data?

Tags: java, linux, console, terminal, protocols

I am trying to connect to a hardware, which works with my other operating system tools (such as minicom).

But now i am writing an application in Java to connect to that device using serial port RS232.

But which native way i should connect from Java? Should i use: http://204.93.165.39:8080/Giovynet/ ? Or is there FREE open source wrappers available for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used rxtx on windoze and it seemed to work ok. there is a linux version: http://www.agaveblue.org/howtos/Comm_How-To.shtml

i have some code that uses this that i can send to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Wikibook on Serial Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) to be helpful.